# how to keep the value of a variable in a closure

Tags: closures, javascript

i need to create multiple javascript functions which have a static **id** inside, so the function itself knows what data to process.

Here is some code:

```
(function(){
  function log(s){
    if(console && console.log) console.log(s);
    else alert(s);
  }
  var i = 10; while (i--){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      // i need i to be 10, 9, 8... here not -1
      log(i);
    },500);
  }
})();
```

The problem ist that **i** allways gets updated by the loop, and i need to prevent this.

Thanks in advance for any help, comments or tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little better approach to using an immediately invoked function in each iteration, is to have your `log()` function return a function.

```
(function(){
  function log(s){
    return function() {
        if(console && console.log) console.log(s);
        else alert(s);
    };
  }
  var i = 10; while (i--){
    window.setTimeout( log( i ),500 );
  }
})();
```

The overall result is that you end up constructing fewer function objects.

If you wanted the calls to be at an interval, either use `setInterval()`, or change this:

```
window.setTimeout( log( i ), 500 );
```

to this:

```
window.setTimeout( log( i ), i * 500 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a function and call it.

```
while (i--) {
    (function(i) {
        // use i here
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wont work i my case. the function will be called delayed.

Comment: @Florian How? setTimeout is executed _inside_, `function(i)` is executed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

```
(function(){
  function log(s){
    if(console && console.log) console.log(s);
    else alert(s);
  }
  var i = 10; while (i--){

    (function() { // start anon func

      var copy = i; // copy loop variable

      window.setTimeout(function(){
        log(copy); // refer to copy
      },500);

    })(); // end anon func and call it immediately
  }
})();
```

Comment: Normally you pass the value to copy to the anonymous function as an argument

Comment: Thanks Daniel for providing an additional example, i think i do understand the concept now!